# MSSQL: calculate user name lenght

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my `users` table I need to calculate count of users by username length. 
For example:

- 200  users has name 1 char length
- 500  users has name 2 chars length
- 1500 users has name 3 chars length
- ...

I created MSSQL query:

```
SELECT 
  TOP 1000
  LEN(nick) as 'title',
  Count(*)
FROM [userstable]
WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY title
```

After I run it I see next problem:

> column 'userstable.Nick' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Could someone explain why?

Comment: You can't use the alias name in the group by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Group by` is logically processed before `Select` so you cannot use alias there

```
SELECT TOP 1000 Len(nick) AS 'title',
                Count(*)
FROM   [userstable] WITH(NOLOCK)
GROUP  BY Len(nick)
```

Also read this article to know about `NOLOCK` [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)